# Custom lint check for tests files

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I integrated a custom lint check as explained [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules/tree/master/android-studio-3), However the checks have no effects on my test code, it generates errors for the java class inside the `main folder but not the`test` folder.

I tried to change `Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE` to `Scope.TEST_SOURCES` and other values when creating the `com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Implementation` however it did not work.

What am I doing wrong? is that not supported?

Answer (score 1):

It is supported, however this only works reliable with Android Studio Plugin 3.0 and later. Also then you'll need to use the Lint Tools `26.0.0` just to be sure.

I construct my Implementation like this `new Implementation(MyDetector.class, EnumSet.of(JAVA_FILE, TEST_SOURCES));`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and eventually figured out what I was doing wrong. I was calling `gradlew <app>:lintInternalRelease`, but release does not acknowledge test classes. `gradlew <app>:lintInternalDebug` did what I wanted.